# Why doesn't docker container start at boot w/ upstart script on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, lxc

Using instructions for [Docker auto-start](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/host_integration/) on Linode VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 and Docker 0.8.1, the specified container does not start on reboot.

Once booted, I am able to

```
~$ sudo start [service-name]
```

and everything goes as planned, but I would also like to container to restart after a reboot.

Is the script in the tutorial not designed to handle reboots?

/etc/default/docker file contains one line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-r=false"
```

/etc/init/service-name.conf is straight from the docker page:

```
description "service description"                                                                                                            
author "me"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
    # Wait for docker to finish starting up first.
    FILE=/var/run/docker.sock
    while [ ! -e $FILE ] ; do
        inotifywait -t 2 -e create $(dirname $FILE)
    done
    /usr/bin/docker start -a db5e61a9afa8
end script
```

Comment: What are the contents of your upstart script and `/etc/default/docker`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point over the past couple of months, the upstart script in the tutorial was changed to remove the loop to wait for docker to start. I removed the loop from my upstart scripts and my containers now restart correctly after a reboot.

My /etc/init/service-name.conf script now looks like this:

```
description "service description"                                                                                                            
author "me"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
    /usr/bin/docker start -a db5e61a9afa8
end script
```

I'm not sure what was wrong with that loop.
Maybe it was pointing to the wrong file on my system, although I didn't make any changes to the default docker install.
For now, I'm just happy the fix involved code removal instead of some complicated work-around.

Comment: It'd be more upstart-ish to change the docker job to emit a signal (docker-started) and have that signal trigger the container jobs to start.

Comment: You cannot stop the container this way by issuing command `stop service-name`. I am facing this issue :(

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using ubuntu 14.04 apt-get flavor of docker. You just need to change the startup script to wait on "docker.io" and not "docker" like so:

```
description "Docker startup script for yum_repo"
author "me"
start on filesystem and started docker.io
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
  /usr/local/bin/docker start -a yum_repo_run
end script
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 as the host and I had the same issue. I found that docker installs a rc script for docker in `/etc/init.d/docker` and at the same time installs an upstart script at /etc/init/docker.conf. I just had to remove the rc script `/etc/init.d/docker` for this issue to go away.

Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: Sadly, this one did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-r=false"
```

This means: Don't restart previously running containers.

Remove the `-r` option or change it to true.

Comment: Right, but the point is to have upstart handle container restarts, not the docker daemon. If the docker daemon starts the container on reboot, the process can't be managed by upstart.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/run/docker.sock` is a socket so you need to use `-S` when testing for existence:

```
FILE=/var/run/docker.sock
while [ ! -S $FILE ] ; do
    inotifywait -t 2 -e create $(dirname $FILE)
done
```